# Can't Limit Number of Checked Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure why the script doesn't work. Want it to uncheck one box when you try to select more than two. For example if you select CHEAP and FAST and then try and select GOOD, FAST is then unchecked.

```js
        document.querySelector('body').className = 'has-js';
        var checked = [];
            [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'), function (checkbox) {
          checkbox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'checkbox', 'trigger');
        if (checkbox.checked && checked.length === 2) {
              var uncheckTarget = checked[Math.floor(Math.random() * checked.length)];
          uncheckTarget.checked = false;
        }
            checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
          });
        });
```

```html
      <div class="container">
            <input type="checkbox" id="fast">
            <label class="red" for="fast">FAST</label>

            <input type="checkbox" id="good">
            <label class="green" for="good">GOOD</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="cheap">
        <label class="blue" for="cheap">CHEAP</label>
          </div>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Works just fine for me without the Google Analytics call - two checkboxes can be checked at most

Comment: Why are you supposing that "it doesn't work" ? What is your code *supposed* to do, to you ?

Comment: the problem with the function that I see that it doesn't seem to be smart enough to know which one you checked...it's always unchecking the 3rd checked item and it sounds like you don't want that.  You only want to uncheck if it's not the checked item...you also have to then handle the special condition when you encounter the 2nd one...1st is checked and 3rd is the caller but its also checked...so you need references to "this" checkbox in the method as well.

Comment: Fiddle without the Google Analytics call seems to work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/8gyj4ek4/

Comment: Thank you Tulir it now seems to function the way it should be

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Although you may have gotten your code to work, it is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to be overly complicated. Also, you should use the `click` event instead of the `change` event for your callback because by the time `change` occurs, the checkmark is already present in the checkbox, so now you'd have to remove it. With `click`, you can just cancel the event, which occurs prior to the checkmark going into the checkbox.

```js
var boxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'));

boxes.forEach(function(chk) {
  chk.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("You already have 2 checkboxes checked. Uncheck one and try again!");
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="fast"><label class="red" for="fast">FAST</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="good"><label class="green" for="good">GOOD</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cheap"><label class="blue" for="cheap">CHEAP</label>
</div>
```